# Lex Unrecognized rule in Lex - Ubuntu

Tags: lex

I'm writing a program in lex, and it gives me the following error:

LexInput.l:12: unrecognized rule

Line 12 is: \"([^\042\134]|"\"(.|[\n]))*\"  printf("string : %s\n", yytext);

Here's my code:

```
    %{
    #include <stdio.h>
    %}

    L [a-zA-Z]
    D [0-9]
    %%
    {L}({L}|{D})*           printf("id : %s\n", yytext);
    [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*      printf("C id : %s\n", yytext);
    [+-]?[0-9]+         printf("integer : %s\n", yytext);
    [0-9]+"."[0-9]+(e[+-]?[0-9]+)?  printf("real : %s\n", yytext);
    \"([^\042\134]|"\"(.|[\n]))*\"  printf("string : %s\n", yytext);
    "/*"([^*]|"*"+[^*)])*"*"+"/"    printf("text comment : /* ... */\n");
    "//".*              printf("line comment : // ... \n");

    "\n" |
    . ;
    %%
    int yywrap()
    {
        return 1; 
    }

    void main()
    {
        yylex();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The line in question has an unclosed double quote, although it is written in such an obfuscated manner that it is not at all obvious.

Here's the pattern from the line:

```
\"([^\042\134]|"\"(.|[\n]))*\"
```

What you meant to write was:

```
\"([^\042\134]|"\\"(.|[\n]))*\"
```

The way it was written, the quoted string starting just after the <kbd>|</kbd> was never closed, because the closing <kbd>"</kbd> was backslash-escaped. However, there is no need to enclose backslash-escaped characters in quotes, since they are already quoted by the backslash.

So here's a possibly more readable version:

```
["]([^"\\]|\\(.|\n))*["]
```

Inside `[]`, quote characters are not special, which is why I prefer using `["]` to represent a literal double-quote. Also, you can just write `\n`; there is no need to enclose it in any other punctuation.